# getNodeById() error (Node-Neo4j, GrapheneDB)

Tags: node.js, heroku, neo4j

I've encountered a strange behaviour when testing getNodeById,

When ID is set to something **i know exists** in the database, the response = null, http://coffeedoc.info/github/thingdom/node-neo4j/master/, states that it should return the node.

When ID is set to something **i know doesn't exist** in the database, the response is a strange object with no good way of interpreting it as an error.

What is going on here?

*(I'm able to create nodes, so everything should be set up correctly)*

*(neo4j version: 2.1.4)*

Code:

```
this.db.getNodeById(**ID**, function (response) {
            console.log('----- START -----');

            console.log(response);

            console.log('----- END -----');
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what that "strange object with no good way of interpreting it as an error" is?

Comment: where do you get the id from?